# How fast is memcached set operation?

Tags: java, memcached

I need to design a cache for storing objects coming in from multiple clients. These clients can all come in parallel. These objects need to stored on memcached, and retrieved later for use.

```
String newKey ;
private synchronized String setData(Data newData) {
    do {
        newKey = createRandomKey() ;
    } while (memcacheClient.get(newKey) != null) ;
    memcacheClient.set(newKey, 10000, newData) ;
}
```

My question is, will this method become a bottleneck for parallel client access ?

OR

Should I create a shared List and a Thread. The thread will do the setData, asynchronously ?

Comment: Apparently you don't have much confidence in the randomness of your random keys, and that loop is pretty costly as it involves a memcache fetch operation.  Is there really no way to ensure that the "random key" is really random and avoid that do while loop altogether?

Comment: Thats what I was thinking, its kinda a corner case thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay of the loop heavily depends on how random createRondomKey can achieve. Do you have to use random keys? Is it possible to come up with some semantic naming schemes (e.g., userid/category/blabla)? That will also save you the efforts to remember the random keys.

Comment: I am trying to develop a session manager. That stores session object identified by a session key. I think I'll remove the loop, its a overkill. Worst case, a old client will be disconnected. Very rare corner condition.